How to Display an Image in a Django Form Instead of Showing Its URL
I have a Django application where I want to display the image in a form when editing an existing product. It's showing the image URL in currently, but I would like to display the actual image itself instead of URL. If that is not possible then remove that currently URL.

from django import forms
from .models import Product
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
Here is form.py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product_name', 'description', 'price', 'image', 'stock', 'category']

I tried by my self but didn't worked

"Current Image:"

that's how I want to show in currently : products/.....jpg,
or if that's not possible then want to remove

where is forms.py

@django.seolpyo.com I updated the question and specified form.py

I think you should use js that creates an img tag whenever the image field value changes.
